# PHP DomDocument XPATH does not match to the HTML real structure

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath, markup

I'm trying to validate the following HTML code (
Please note the text content inside IMG tag, which is structurally correct as markup, but invalid as HTML):

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="./">
            Some Text
        </img>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using PHP and DomDocument, I try to read entire tree with XPATH:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse = 0;
$dom->loadHTML($htmlSource);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$allNodes = $xpath->query("//node()");
```

The result I get:

```
/html
/html/head
/html/body
/html/body/#text[1]
/html/body/img
/html/body/#text[2]
```

which obviously does not match the exact HTML structure.
What I expected to see is

```
....
    /html/body/img/#text
....
```

Why does XPATH interpret the tree this way?
How can I get it to work as I expected?

Comment: Try loading it as XML. In HTML `img` has no children. Libxml DOM tries to repair documents. Nothing to do with Xpath, just the loading function.

Comment: Thanks ThW, I, already tried it. Unfortunately,  most of the files I need to parse are not well formed and the LoadXML function fails (while LoadHTML succeeds). The example above was just for illustration, the real world html content is much more messy and complex

Comment: You can try using HTMLTidy (It supports XML, too). But this are different modes for the parser (XML vs. HTML), so he has fix the DOM that way. It is the defined behavior.